# How to do useful tests with JUnit and dependency injection?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependencies

Let's suppose we have a Java class like this:

```java
class MyClass {
    private final DependencyA da;
    private final DependencyB db;

    public MyClass(DependencyA da, DependencyB db) {
        this.da = da;
        this.db = db;
    }

    public String foo() {
        ResultA resultA = da.someMethodA();
        ResultB resultB = db.someMethodB(resultA);
 
        return resultB.id;
    }
}
```

How should I do the unit test for `foo` method? I've read on internet that I should mock the dependencies (in this case with Mockito):

```java
// imports...

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MyClassTest {
    @Mock DependencyA da;
    @Mock DependencyB db;
    @InjectMocks MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    void foo() {
        when(da.someMethodA()).thenReturn(new ResultA());
        when(db.someMethodB(any(ResultA.class)).thenReturn(new ResultB());

        ResultB resultB = myClass.foo();

        assertNotNull(resultB);
    }
}
```

But I feel that it's a useless test because I'm mocking the whole `foo` method. Should I do an integration test instead?

Comment: you may write `verify(da, times(1)).someMethodA()` and now you check that `#foo` is calling `da#someMethodA` :)

Comment: You are not "mocking the whole `foo` method". The implementation of `foo` in `MyClass` is being executed.

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for confirming that the test was right, I'm trying to not doing tests just to accomplish a minimum coverage.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov! I will complement my tests with that method

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on some things, if you want to test how the behavior of the foo method is given a certain input you are fine with that unit test.

But if you want to test the actual behavior of those dependencies methods, you could be looking to integration tests, let’s say one of those methods make some I/O operation.

Not saying that for these cases you couldn’t be doing unit tests as well, but if you are willing to not only mock those behaviors, consider these things…